# Why does an axios post request to django get empty data?

Tags: django, reactjs

Returns a 404 error
Here is a request with react

```
const addItemToBasket = (item) => {
        dispatch({type: ADD_ITEM_TO_BASKET, payload: item})
        console.log(item.id, store.get('email'))
        axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
        axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'
        axios.post("http://localhost:8000/cart/add", {
            uid: item.id, amount: 1, email: store.get('email')
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
```

Here is the django function
[image]

Comment: try const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:8000/cart/add",
            data: { uid: item.id, amount: 1, email: store.get('email') },
            headers: { 'xsrfCookieName': 'csrftoken', 'xsrfHeaderName': 'X-CSRFToken'},
            withCredentials: true
        }

        axios(options)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });

Comment: APPEND_SLASH = False

CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

REACT_DOMEN = 'http://localhost:3000'
DJANGO_DOMEN = 'http://localhost:8000'